# Backed up and formatted SD card, now "app isnt installed" error

Tags: external-sd

So i was having this error on my laptop which didnt allow files to be copied or moved to and from my SD card. The error happens mostly when copying to my sd card. When i try it says something like the device disconnected or isnt responding

Anyways after googling the problem, i came across a solution that said to format my SD card, so i backed it up onto my laptop, formatted the sd card and put the original files back onto the sd card (it didnt fix the problem, putting the files back on was a struggle and eventually had to put them on my web server on my laptop and download from my phone)

While the sd card was formatted, i got the problem with not being able to load any of the apps, it said "app not installed" (this was expected since most of my apps were on the SD card) and i thought the problem would be fixed when i put the files back on however i still get the "app isnt installed" error. I cant move the apps to the internal storage from the settings since it says the app doesnt exist

So

Issue #1: how do i get the apps back? Re downloading them is a pain since my internal storage is pretty full already and i dont have much space for downloading apps

Issue #2: how do i prevent the error message from happening when copying files to my SD card? Ive tried using different cables, ports, uninstalling drivers and even tried it on a different laptop but it still doesnt work which makes me think its something to do with the phone. For some reason it allowed me to copy the sd card content to my laptop so im not sure why that was.

Thanks for reading, i hope someone is able to help. Thanks

Comment: Did you try formatting the sd card from your Android phone (or a linux machine)? Did you try another sd card?

Comment: Yes i formatted it with my phone. I havent tried a different sd card but i will do tomorrow. Im not sure it is the sd card however since the whole phone disconnects

Comment: When copying stuff back, did you include the `.android_secure` (note the dot at the start) directory? Because that's where (parts of) your moved apps reside. This directory is usually *not* exposed on the device, and probably neither shown when mounted from your device to the PC (also see [these posts](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=.android_secure) on this directory and issue).

Comment: My windows explorer is set to show hidden files and so is my file explorer on my phone so that folder should have been visible however all the times i browsed my SD card before, i've never seen this folder, not even when i copied the files to my PC